# Is there a map showing historical average precipitation at a specific time of year?

Tags: online-resources, planning, weather-and-climate, maps

For planning outdoor events, such as group camping trips, it would be useful to be able to look at a map showing average precipitation across history for a given time of year, week or day.  For example, a map showing average rainfall for the second week of March. Does anyone know of such a thing?  I'm looking for a generalized tool, but if it helps the specific regions I'm most likely to use this would be northern California.

Comment: You might accelerate getting a useful answer if you nailed it down to where. An answer for Alaska will be worthless in Siberia.

Comment: @GayotFow Well I was looking for a genralized tool, but I added a region.

Comment: It looks a lot better now. Soon you will have some really great answers.

Comment: You can find average rainfalls for areas, on various climate websites.  But most of this data comes from a few collection points like airports, tv stations, etc.  The accurately map it by area on a regional map would require a lot more data collection points.

Comment: [This tag combo](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-and-climate+online-resources) has lots of ideas, including [Is there a website with historical temperatures?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36405/is-there-a-website-with-historical-temperatures) which looks dupey...

Comment: Could be a fun project to build based on reanalysis data.  Actual *measurements* are sparse and country-dependent, but reanalysis data fills up the gaps in time and space with models.  The accuracy does vary considerably per region, though.  Do you need an interactive map or could you download a couple of hundred GB of reanalysis data and produce the map with your favourite analysis tool (Python, R, Matlab) yourself?

Comment: @gerrit Agreed, though it won't be me.  It would require me to develop both statistical and mapping skills I don't have and I have a backlog of hobbyist projects that are much more readily accessible to me.  ;-)

Comment: @AakashM I agree that that question is very closely related but I don't think it's a dupe. Rainfall vs temperature is irrelevant, since all the answers to that question seem to cover rainfall, temperature and all kinds of other climate measurements. However, this question specifically asks for a map, whereas all the answers seem to just give graphs for specific points. (Yes, I'm aware that weather data is generally only available from fixed weather stations, but one could produce a map either by interpolating or by using historical rainfall radar.)

Answer (score 3):

[Climate.org](https://www.climate.gov/maps-data/data-snapshots/totalprecip-monthly-cmb-2016-03-00?theme=Precipitation) should have what you are looking for. Their website gives downloadable maps for different times of year, and testing lots of different conditions such as rainfall.

Here's an example for the average rainfall in March 2016 in the US :
[image]

For example, we can see from this that the rainfall in March 2016 in Florida was about 1 inch. We can compare this to New York, which had about 3 inches. We can then compare this with other months using the tools on the website.

There are many more [options available on the website](https://www.climate.gov/maps-data) such as Average Temperatures, Outlooks, Drought Monitors etc

For a more general view, check out these sites;

- [National Weather Service - Data for anywhere in the world](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/regional_monitoring/1cpcp1.png)
- [Intellicast - Provides Data And Maps for Various Locations](http://www.intellicast.com/Local/History.aspx?location=USNY9472)

Comment: Really close, I did find those in my searching before asking here.  But I can't find a way to show average precipitation for a given month/week accross *all years*, not specific to 1 year.

Comment: You could get that in a table, but is it a must for it to be on a map? @RossPatterson Are you wanting a map showing average temperature for everywhere since records began?

Comment: Per the question: yes on map, no temperature (the question says precipitation).  As for across history, since records began is not necessary, in fact "last decade" would probably be best, but I really don't care how long the history is.

Comment: I mean, this shows yearly better http://www.climate-charts.com/World-Climate-Maps.html - I'll have another look to see if I can find anything for monthly. @RossPatterson

Comment: Would an answer with this in help? http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/temp-and-precip/global-maps/ @RossPatterson

Comment: I don't see any way to see average per-month *across years*.

Comment: This link only shows Australia - http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/climate_averages/rainfall/index.jsp?period=jan&area=Oz but would some data like this for other locations be useful? @RossPatterson

Comment: Map doesn't work for me on Linux Chrome, but if it did, yes that's what I'm asking for, but for US (and Canada optimally).

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://www.weatherbase.com/ in the past
Put in a city and get monthly averages highs and lows, rain and snow stats etc.  You can also drill down to a particular day but I don’t think it will do it by week.

Comment: Does the website have a map facility as the question asks, or just data in tables @Dax ?