# Visualising the world by apparent temperature at a given time of the year

Tags: online-resources, weather-and-climate, maps, asia

My overseas trips tend to be in the middle of the year (roughly some time between June and September), as Australian workplaces tend to have a Christmas shutdown straddling Christmas and the new year.

However, I want to avoid going to excessively hot destinations during the northern hemisphere summer. For example, [Vietnam](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vietnam#Climate) isn't all that suitable because of either temperature or rain for all three of its regions. I want to go to locations reasonably close to Australia, and I've already been to Japan, South Korea and Taiwan, with many of the Asian alternatives being closer to the equator.

How can I visualise the average [apparent temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_temperature) at a specified time of year, so that I can compare locations and see the effect of changing the time of travel?

I'm predominantly interested in the Asian region.

Related questions: [Is there a map showing historical average precipitation at a specific time of year?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68865/is-there-a-map-showing-historical-average-precipitation-at-a-specific-time-of-ye) and [Is there a website with historical temperatures and weather data?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36405/is-there-a-website-with-historical-temperatures-and-weather-data)

Comment: You should post this on one of the more technology focused stack sites

Answer (score 3):

I use the https://www.accuweather.com and check the weather from last year. For example, you can check the weather in Chicago from last January [here](https://www.accuweather.com/pt/us/chicago-il/60608/february-weather/348308?monyr=2/1/2018) and you will have an idea.

Comment: This is what i'm using currently to check weather in Europe for my future trip. It's really good and easy to use.

Comment: It is a good method but I would add to it, a site or map that shows a longer time average and/or check out several years. Some areas are not as predictable.

Answer (score 3):

With an atlas.

[image: Atlas]
(this example taken from [the 93rd edition of Philip's Modern School Atlas](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Philips-Modern-School-Atlas-World/dp/0540077844/ref=sr_1_fkmr3_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1521723593&sr=1-2-fkmr3&keywords=philips%20modern%20school%20atlas%2093rd%20edition))

Comment: Today I learned that "Willy-Willies" happen in Australia from January to March.  (See the lower right map.)

Comment: The example you've given is displaying actual temperature, rather than [apparent temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_temperature)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert it's an Aboriginal word, even though it sounds like an English name.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Other atlases will have different, potentially more comprehensive, information (this is my old secondary school one, it's not super-detailed); I was not suggesting this specific one, or that the information in the photo was exactly what you were looking for, simply that that's the kind of information they contain. (I like books, which is why I suggested them; it's not a 100 % serious answer.)