# Can I expect "winter" scenery in Iceland in April?

Tags: weather-and-climate, iceland

I am willing to travel to Iceland, renting a car and making a trip across the country. What I expect seeing the most is viewing the "winter" scenery of Iceland: snow, glaciers, frozen waterfalls, ice caves, northern lights and maybe a little ski.

**Will those still be present at mid-April across Iceland? Or only in certain areas?**

**Should I travel in other dates?**

**Will car accessibility be a big issue in that time? (due to road blocks).**

Some have described April as "spring" in Iceland, though spring probably has a different meaning in Iceland, therefore I am not sure what to expect from the scenery.

Comment: Skiing is possible in March, haven't heard of skiing in April though. I would move your trip to early March if you want to ski.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, about the rest: can I expect winter scenery in April?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a website with historical temperatures and weather data?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36405/is-there-a-website-with-historical-temperatures-and-weather-data)

Comment: No, I do not think April is the right month for what you're after. But that's based on my trips passing through Greenland, not Iceland.

Comment: Northern lights are harder to see, not because they do not happen but because the days are already longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went to Iceland for 10 days in March-April 2009. You can see my [photos from the trip](https://hewgill.com/photo/trips/islands-world-2009/iceland/index.html).

1. Winter sights will be present, but probably only in certain areas. One day we [drove through a blizzard](https://hewgill.com/photo/trips/islands-world-2009/iceland/IMG_6916.JPG.html), Gullfoss was [very cold and windy](https://hewgill.com/photo/trips/islands-world-2009/iceland/IMG_6891.JPG.html), but other days were [dry and clear](https://hewgill.com/photo/trips/islands-world-2009/iceland/IMG_7155.JPG.html). In Akureyri, [skiing was available](https://hewgill.com/photo/trips/islands-world-2009/iceland/IMG_7062.JPG.html).
2. Since I have a sample size of one trip, it's hard to suggest what dates might be best for you.
3. Our [hired car](https://hewgill.com/photo/trips/islands-world-2009/iceland/IMG_7004.JPG.html) was a 4WD Škoda wagon with studded tyres. It did very well for the conditions at that time of year. The main ring road is [kept clear](https://hewgill.com/photo/trips/islands-world-2009/iceland/IMG_7038.JPG.html) as much as possible because it's the only land route from one place to another. Many side roads were closed so it's a good idea to keep an eye on the [Iceland road conditions](http://www.road.is/travel-info/road-conditions-and-weather/) - check that site every day before you set out.